# Does SystemVerilog support nested packages?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have a tool that produces .sv RAL files for use in a UVM testbench. The problem is that this file creates the register block as a package. My issue is that for my testbench, I want to import multiple .sv RAL files (representing different reg blocks).

To do this, I want to create a single package **all_my_regs_pkg.sv** and `include the other packages into this package. I get a compilation error and looking into it, it looks like there isn't support for nested packages in SystemVerilog.

So do I need to manually import each of the reg block packages when I want to use them? I suppose I could create a file with the imports and just `include it, but is this the only way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SystemVerilog does not allow nesting of package declarations. The best thing for you do do is to define a file that is a list of package import statements and have users `` `include `` that file where needed.

The is another SV feature that allows you to chain package imports, but you have to explicitly `export` a symbol that you import into a package to be imported by the next package. See Section *26.6 Exporting imported names from packages* in the 1800-2012 LRM